# Javascript Youtube API: buffering for ever - UIWebView iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API in UIWebView.

I have created a NSString with the HTML5 player that I load in the UIWebView. Everything works perfectly on iPhone 5 and iPad.

But, if I test the app using an iPhone 4, the player returns the buffering state all the time. Only if I explicitly press the play button, the player starts playing, without stopping again for buffering. It seems that although the video has been buffered, the player still gives me this state.

Is anyone aware of this problem? Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

In LBYouTubePlayerViewController.m file

Replace Following method on yr old Method....

then test...

```
      -(NSURL*)_extractYouTubeURLFromFile:(NSString *)html error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
NSString *JSONStart = nil;
// NSString *JSONStartFull = @"ls.setItem('PIGGYBACK_DATA', \")]}'";
NSString *JSONStartFull = @"bootstrap_data = \")]}'";
NSString *JSONStartShrunk = [JSONStartFull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
if ([html rangeOfString:JSONStartFull].location != NSNotFound)
    JSONStart = JSONStartFull;
else if ([html rangeOfString:JSONStartShrunk].location != NSNotFound)
    JSONStart = JSONStartShrunk;

if (JSONStart != nil) {
    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];
    [scanner scanUpToString:JSONStart intoString:nil];
    [scanner scanString:JSONStart intoString:nil];

    NSString *JSON = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"}\";" intoString:&JSON];
    JSON = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@}",JSON]; // Add closing bracket } to get vallid JSON again
    // [scanner scanUpToString:@"\");" intoString:&JSON];
    JSON = [self _unescapeString:JSON];
    NSError* decodingError = nil;
    NSDictionary* JSONCode = nil;

    // First try to invoke NSJSONSerialization (Thanks Mattt Thompson)

    id NSJSONSerializationClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSJSONSerialization");
    SEL NSJSONSerializationSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"dataWithJSONObject:options:error:");
    if (NSJSONSerializationClass && [NSJSONSerializationClass respondsToSelector:NSJSONSerializationSelector]) {
        JSONCode = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&decodingError];
    }
    else {
        JSONCode = [JSON objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone error:&decodingError];
    }

    if (decodingError) {
        // Failed

        *error = decodingError;
    }
    else {
        // Success

        NSDictionary *dict = [JSONCode objectForKey:@"content"];
        NSDictionary *dictTemp = [dict objectForKey:@"video"];
        NSArray* videos = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"fmt_stream_map"];

        NSString* streamURL = nil;
        if (videos.count) {
            NSString* streamURLKey = @"url";

            if (self.quality == LBYouTubePlayerQualityLarge) {
                streamURL = [[videos objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:streamURLKey];
            }
            else if (self.quality == LBYouTubePlayerQualityMedium) {
                unsigned int index = MAX(0, videos.count-2);
                streamURL = [[videos objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:streamURLKey];
            }
            else {
                streamURL = [[videos lastObject] objectForKey:streamURLKey];
            }
        }

        if (streamURL) {
            return [NSURL URLWithString:streamURL];
        }
        else {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kLBYouTubePlayerControllerErrorDomain code:2 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Couldn't find the stream URL." forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
        }
    }
}
else {
    *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kLBYouTubePlayerControllerErrorDomain code:3 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"The JSON data could not be found." forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
}

return nil;
}
```

Comment: I do not user LBYouTubePlayerView. UIWebView is used in the app. Thanks for the response in any case!

Comment: i had facing same problem bro..but..i used LBYoutubPlayer... https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView/commit/1927d204c22a07b0928ab35dcc3e683082c05b43#LBYouTubeView/LBYouTubeExtractor.m     check it i hope u will got yr problem..may be..